# Web Deploy randomly stopped working - maximum number of sync passes '10' has been exceeded

Tags: windows, iis, windows-server-2019, windows-server-2022, webdeploy

We have a Windows Server 2022 and Windows Server 2019 servers with Web Deploy 3.6 installed. Everything has been working perfectly and we had been able to deploy perfectly without issue. We have been able to deploy manually from Visual Studio (publishing a site). We can also deploy using Github actions such as this:

> dotnet build WebsiteProjects\Website.Site\Website.Site.csproj
> /p:Configuration=Release
> /p:PublishProfile=WebsiteProjects\Website.Site\Properties\PublishProfiles\LIVE.pubxml
> /p:DeployOnBuild=True /p:Password="${{ secrets.PROD_PASS }}"

However over the last month, we just simply cannot deploy things any more.

When deploying from Visual Studio we get this error:

> C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\sdk\8.0.100\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Publish\targets\PublishTargets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Publish.MSDeploy.targets(140,5):
> Error : Web deployment task failed. (The synchronization is being
> stopped because the maximum number of sync passes '10' has been
> exceeded even though all the changes could not be applied. This could
> occur if there are external changes being made to the destination.)
> Publish failed to deploy.

If we use GitHub actions, we get this error:

> MSDEPLOY : error : The synchronization is being stopped because the
> maximum number of sync passes '10' has been exceeded even though all
> the changes could not be applied. This could occur if there are
> external changes being made to the destination.
> [C:\actions-runner_work\Site\Site\WebServiceProjects\WebService.SiteApi\WebService.SiteApi.csproj]

Absolutely nothing has changed on these servers for years, with exception of Windows Updates, and adding/removing sites. The publish profiles have not changed either.

Disabling Windows Defender does not help. Restarting the Web Deployment agent does not help. Restarting the server does not help. Restarting IIS or disabling the site while deploying does not help.

*Sometimes* if I stop the site and delete all the files in the inetpub folder the deploy will work - this seems to be the only way to get web deploy to work, but its not consistent.

Note we tried this with .NET 7 and .NET 8 SDKs - same issue. I [logged](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Web-deployment-task-failed---Maximum-num/10512580?port=1026&fsid=7ca2e6a4-6ba0-4730-821e-d4f3a53819f6&ref=native&refTime=1701279114860&refUserId=ba77ed44-fbcd-68d8-84db-5223bc7fd16b) this through Visual Studio as I initially thought it was an issue from one of their updates. I also don't see anything interesting in the event viewer.

Really am at a loss as we are now unable to run GitHub actions for deployments and cannot even deploy manually from Visual Studio to the servers. Any suggestions on how to fix or diagnose what is happening?

[image]

Example publish profile:

```
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <WebPublishMethod>MSDeploy</WebPublishMethod>
    <LastUsedBuildConfiguration>Release</LastUsedBuildConfiguration>
    <LastUsedPlatform>Any CPU</LastUsedPlatform>
    <SiteUrlToLaunchAfterPublish>https://...</SiteUrlToLaunchAfterPublish>
    <LaunchSiteAfterPublish>true</LaunchSiteAfterPublish>
    <ExcludeApp_Data>false</ExcludeApp_Data>
    <TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>
    <ProjectGuid>2ca81a89-d8b9-4f72-ba22-dd26757ef8d6</ProjectGuid>
    <SelfContained>false</SelfContained>
    <_IsPortable>true</_IsPortable>
    <MSDeployServiceURL>...</MSDeployServiceURL>
    <DeployIisAppPath>...</DeployIisAppPath>
    <RemoteSitePhysicalPath />
    <MSDeployPublishMethod>WMSVC</MSDeployPublishMethod>
    <EnableMSDeployBackup>true</EnableMSDeployBackup>
    <UserName>Administrator</UserName>
    <_SavePWD>true</_SavePWD>
    <SkipExtraFilesOnServer>false</SkipExtraFilesOnServer>
    <EnableMSDeployAppOffline>true</EnableMSDeployAppOffline>
    <MSDeployUseChecksum>true</MSDeployUseChecksum>
    <AllowUntrustedCertificate>True</AllowUntrustedCertificate>
    <RuntimeIdentifier>win-x64</RuntimeIdentifier>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Comment: `cannot even deploy manually` not sure what that means, but what about a robocopy of a staging folder to production? Or checking a target server to see if there are any open handles to anything in the target folder?

Comment: By manually, I mean using the Publish to IIS process in Visual Studio. Automatic would be using a CI pipeline (in my case Github). But to emphasize again, this is a relatively new error which has stumped me.

Comment: It should be relatively easy and straightforward to use handle.exe or process explorer to determine what has an open handle for the file(s).

Answer (score 0):

Changing the MSDeployUseChecksum to false seemed to fix this for me:

```
 <MSDeployUseChecksum>false</MSDeployUseChecksum>
```

No idea why though.

Comment: Interesting. When checking files for overwriting, the default is a modified date check. This setting uses a checksum test. My guess would be the locking semantics for the code for the checksum is incompatible with the current state of any files with open handles. The default/no checksum shouldn't be a problem if only one person deploys, or if you have fixed releases and deploy a known fixed set of files for a given release. Procmon on the target host should show the state of any files/handles during the deployment.